# Comparing API call field delta in a loop without storing data

Tags: python, api, loops, python-requests

I am attempting to make an API call to a website which provides me a particular stocks value. The goal for me here is to make a little ticker in python that will show me the amount the value has changed after sleeping the program or having the program refresh every 15 minutes.

I am having no issue getting the value the first time, nor the second time in order to make the calculation and message I would like. This is currently all in one while true loop (which worked great when I didn't want historical data) so once it returns to the first API call it has no data to reference to show a delta, percentage, etc.

Am I missing something conceptually on how this would work? I am wondering if pandas could be my friend here. Or the use of more functions? I am trying to think but struggling how I could loop them through each other.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to show the change, you need to use at least one temporary variable to hold your previous state, something like:

```
while True:
    # assuming your_api_call() returns a number:
    value = your_api_call() - locals().get("value", 0)
    print("Change since the last call: {}".format(value))
    time.sleep(900)  # sleep for 15 minutes
```

Comment: i am not familiar with locals() or a temporary variable. Will do more digging, thanks for the direction :)